# ExtJS 5: Setting initialized config variables won't stick after setting from controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

On one controller, I have a function that handles a drill down that sets that record's information on another controller's config variables.

It seems to set them fine the from first controller. When it switches to the other controller, it says those variables are undefined. What is going on?

Controller handling drill down:

```
// Set site name for Site Summary
 MyApp.app.getController('otherController').setSiteId(siteId);
 MyApp.app.getController('otherController').setSiteName(siteName);

 console.log(MyApp.app.getController('otherController').getSiteId());
 console.log(MyApp.app.getController('otherController').getSiteName());
 // Prints out the correct values that are supposed to be set
```

Other controller where the values aren't sticking:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.otherController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        siteId: -1,
        siteName: ''
    },

    init: function() {
    this.listen( {
        component: {            
            'somePnl': {
                beforerender: this.onBeforeRender
            },

// stuff

    onBeforeRender: function() {
        console.log("this.siteName = " + this.siteName);
        console.log("this.siteId = " + this.siteId);
    },
    // Prints out 'undefined'
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why the setting of those variables aren't sticking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExtJS recommends using generated setter and getter for configs. The direct access is not documented.

Doc: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-config

So using

```
console.log("this.siteName = " + this.getSiteName());
console.log("this.siteId = " + this.getSiteId());
```

is best practice and should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently having the underscore seems to be working...

```
console.log("this.siteName = " + this._siteName);
console.log("this.siteId = " + this._siteId);
```

Comment: If it's a config, use the getter, `this.getSiteName()`, `this.getSideId()`.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli You're correct, I found that out last night.